# add actions to actor inside stack

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a libGDX `Stack`, And I added two actor to it.
When I added `Action` to the button, this action not work. WHY ??

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
stack.add(button);
stack.add(label);

button.addAction(Actions.forever(Actions.sequence(Actions.scaleTo(1f, 1f, 1f, Interpolation.sine),Actions.scaleTo(1.1f, 1.1f, 1f, Interpolation.sine))));

stage.addActor(stack);
```

Comment: Do you call stage.act(); somewhere? In other words, could you show us your render method?

Comment: stage.act(delta);           stage.draw();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable transformation for the button:

```
button.setTransform(true);
```

It says that this is true by default, but this is only valid for `Group`, all the other implementations set it to false in their constructor (`Button` extends `Table` and `Table` sets it to false).

I guess this is done to improve performance (transforming everything is costly), but the Javadoc is clearly confusing at this point, so you might write the developers of libgdx.